# strange img src path, not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css

first of all sorry for the silly title. 
I found [solved by flexbox](https://github.com/philipwalton/solved-by-flexbox), I cloned it to localhost, and the site is just crap for me. It works on a really strange way, no headers in the index, the images not shown:

```
<img class="Feature-image" alt="Better, Simpler Grids" src="{{ '/images/grids.jpg' | absolute }}">
```

it is a really silly question but with what technique is this repo written?

Comment: Seems like some kind of template engine? I mean {{ this }} looks like template engine, it won't work using clear HTML

Comment: Isn't it supposed to run on server with ruby  support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) template engine. [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) uses it.

Basically, it is a code for Ruby interpreter.

It takes string `'/images/grids.jpg'` and apply the `absolute` filter. It returns absolute (prepends domain name in production mode) URL for that image.

To view the site you should install Ruby and Jekyll. Then run:

```
$ jekyll serve
# => Now browse to http://localhost:4000
```

Alternatively you may run `$ jekyll build` and then watch static version of the site from `_site` folder. Although it may prepend url from `_config.yml` to all links. I do not remember its behavior.

Quote from http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/ :

> Jekyll is a simple, blog-aware, static site generator. It takes a template directory containing raw text files in various formats, runs it through Markdown (or Textile) and Liquid converters, and spits out a complete, ready-to-publish static website suitable for serving with your favorite web server. Jekyll also happens to be the engine behind GitHub Pages, which means you can use Jekyll to host your project’s page, blog, or website from GitHub’s servers for free.

Comment: ommagaad, ty @halfbit thanks too

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar syntax when reading about templating in ember.js. See http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/handlebars-basics/
The templating is based on Handlebars. See http://handlebarsjs.com/